# Fermi's Golden Rule and Density of States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, perturbation-theory, density-of-states, fermis-golden-rule

I know Fermi's Golden Rule in the form
$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \sum_{f}\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\delta (E_f - E_i)|M_{fi}|^2,$$
where $\Gamma_{fi}$ is the probability transition rate, $M_{fi}$ are the transition matrix elements.

I'm struggling to do a derivation based on the density of states. I know that under certain circumstances it's a good approximation to replace $\sum_f$ with $\int_F \rho(E_f) \textrm{d}E_f$ to calculate the transition probability, for some energy range $F$.

Doing this calculation I obtain
$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \int \rho(E_f) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\delta (E_f - E_i) |M_{fi}|^2\textrm{d}E_f.$$
Now assuming that the $M_{fi}$ are constant in the energy range under the integral we get
$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \rho(E_i) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |M_{fi}|^2.$$
Now this is **absolutely not** what is written anywhere else. Other sources pull the $\rho(E_f)$ out of the integral to obtain [Fermi's Golden Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) of the form
$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \rho(E_f) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |M_{fi}|^2$$
for any $f$ with $E_f$ in $F$ which makes much more physical sense. But why is what I've done wrong? If anything it should be more precise, because I have actually done the integral! Where have I missed something?

Comment: It's the same thing because $E_i=E_f$ in this treatment, isn't it?

Comment: Useful answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/12493/226902

Answer (score 4):

I) Well, OP evidently knows that it is the density $\rho_f(E_f)$ of *final* (rather than *initial*) states that appear in [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule)

$$  \Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \rho_f(E_f) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |W_{fi}|^2.\tag{1}$$

Here we adorn the density $\rho_f$ with a subscript $f$, to make that point clear, following a suggestion by MarkWayne. Instead it seems that OP's actual question is:

> *Must the energy $E_f$ [which here denotes a pertinent average of final states that we summed over in a sufficiently small energy interval, and which appears inside $\rho_f(E_f)$ in eq. (1)] approximately match the energy $E_i$ of the initial state $i$, or not?*

II) A crucial role is played by the *time-dependence* of the interaction potential $V(t)$ in the Hamiltonian

$$ H~=~H_0+V(t).\tag{2} $$

For instance, in the harmonic perturbation [1], the interaction potential reads

$$ V(t)~=~\sum_{\pm}W^{\pm} e^{\pm\mathrm{i}\Omega t}, \tag{3}$$

where $\Omega$ is the angular frequency of absorption/stimulated emission. (We need at least *two* terms in the potential (3) to make the interaction operator $V(t)$ Hermitian.) One may show that this favors transitions of the form

$$ E_f~\approx~E_i\pm\hbar\Omega.\tag{4}$$

So in the harmonic perturbation, $\rho_f(E_f)$ and $\rho_f(E_i)$ are in general different.

III) However, in the derivations of [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) in many elementary textbooks (which always use *time-dependent* perturbation theory), the interaction term $V(t)$ is often treated  as *time-independent* (corresponding to $\Omega=0$). This means that the initial and final state in such time-independent treatments must have approximately the same energy, cf. also a comment by Lubos Motl.

For more information, see e.g. also my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/91794/2451).

References:

1. J.J. Sakurai, *Modern Quantum Mechanics,* 1994, Section 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

As proposed by Lubos, the delta function you started with $\delta(E_i-E_f)$ forces the final result to be invariant by $E_i \leftrightarrow E_f$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite see this - could you expand on your argument perhaps?

Comment: Well, are you familiar with identity:$$\delta(x-x_0)f(x) = \delta(x-x_0)f(x_0)$$ true for distributions, it implies quite directly that you can change $\rho(E_f)$ for $\rho(E_i)$ in your second equation.

Comment: Oh of course - apologies for missing that. But surely in general $\rho(E_i)$ and $\rho(E_f)$ are different even if $E_i = E_f$? For example the decay of one particle into two gives you an extra degree of freedom in $\rho(E_f)$ that you didn't have in $\rho(E_i)$. Or is this logic wrong?

Comment: Dear Edward, you're summing or integrating over $f$ and the integrand depends on $M_{fi}$ and you decided you may eliminate the summation/integral completely. This implicitly means that for each energy $E_f$, the state must actually be unique. Otherwise you would have to keep the sum over the other quantum numbers that commute with the energy.

Comment: Otherwise, Edward, it's hard to understand why you think that $\rho(E_i)$ may be different from $\rho(E_f)$ if $E_i=E_f$. If the argument of a function, $\rho$ in this case, is the same, the value of the function is also the same, isn't it? Note that we're not implying $i=f$: this much isn't the case because the state $|i\rangle$ isn't a function of $E_i$. But things explicitly written to be functions are functions.

Comment: I think the point of confusion here is that $\rho(E)$ is the *density of final states*. Perhaps the notation would be more clear if $\rho_f(E)$ were written instead. Now it should be clear that since energy is conserved $\rho_f(E_f)=\rho_f(E_i)$. Note that the density of initial states, which you might write as $\rho_i(E)$ is not equal to $\rho_f(E)$, as your comment, "But surely..." seems to suggest.

Comment: @MarkWayne - that makes a huge amount of sense. I was thinking that $\rho(E_i)$ was the density of initial states. In fact it's not. It's the density of final states at energy $E_i$! So $\rho(E_i)=\rho(E_f)$ makes perfect sense, and there's no difference between the two formulae I've written in the question. Is that a fair summary? Thanks so much for your help, everyone!

Comment: @MarkWayne I'm even more confused by what you think was confusing Edward. Why do you say there can be subscripts $i$ and $f$ for the density of states $\rho$? In deriving FGR we treat the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H$ as the dominant piece, which has an associated density of states $\rho(E)$. There is thus only ONE density of states ever, and it is a function of $E$ as measured by $H$. So to me it doesn't make sense to put a $i$ or $f$ as subscripts in $\rho$ to say that there are two functions $\rho_i(E)$ and $\rho_f(E)$. There aren't two 'unperturbed' Hamiltonians! Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @nervxxx - Sure, you can write the density of states as an operator $\rho(E) = \pi \delta(E-H_0)$ (up to normalization dependent factors), diagonal in the basis of asymptotic states. The discussion here allows for the possibility that there are different particles in the initial and final states.

Answer (score 2):

The key is understanding the transition from summation to integration over energy. We start with
$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \sum_{f}\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\delta (E_f - E_i)|M_{fi}|^2,$$
where summation over $f$ mean summation over *all quantum numbers of the final states*. We now assume that *the matrix element is dependent only on the energies*, i.e., it can be written as
$$M_{fi}=M(E_f,E_i),$$
and we replace summation by the integration over the energy of the final states:
$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \int \rho(E_f) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\delta (E_f - E_i) |M(E_f, E_i)|^2\textrm{d}E_f.$$

The second important element is using the basic property of the delta function, already mentioned in the comments and other answers:
$$
\int f(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx=\int f(x_0)\delta(x-x_0)dx=f(x_0)$$
(provided that the integration interval contains $x_0$.)
Thus
$$\Gamma_{fi} = \rho(E_f) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |M(E_f, E_f)|^2=\rho(E_i) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |M(E_i, E_i)|^2,$$
where *it is understood that the initial and the final energies are the same*. This is however less transparent than writing $M_{fi}$, which explicitly points out at the nature of the matrix element.

**Remark:** Personally, I find this textbook method of introducing the density-of-states as overcomplicating the issue. A quite general definition is
$$
\rho(E)=\sum_f\delta(E-E_f),$$ in which case the final equation is readily obtained as
$$\Gamma_{fi} = \sum_{f}\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\delta (E_f - E_i)|M(E_f, E_i)|^2=
\left[\sum_{f}\delta (E_f - E_i)\right]\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|M(E_i, E_i)|^2=
\rho(E_i)\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|M(E_i, E_i)|^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

While the answers above already answered your question, I would like to recommend a paper by myself:  [Nonsmooth and level-resolved dynamics illustrated with a periodically driven tight binding model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4280).

In this paper, we derived Fermi golden rule as a by-product. Our derivation does not use the delta function.

I believe our derivation is much simpler and more transparent than those in textbooks. It is just a mathematical property of the [sinc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) function.