# What is the physical meaning of the "decay rate" in Fermis golden rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

As far as I understood, [Fermi's golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) gives a prediction of the transition rate in a perturbed quantum system $H_0+V$ between two eigenstates of the unperturbed system $H_0$, say from $\left| i\right>$ to $\left| f\right>$ with eigenenergies $E_i,E_f$. The prediction is perturbative in the first order of $V$.

The result is, that the rate equals

$$\gamma_{i\to f} = 2\pi |\left<f|V|i\right>|^2 \delta(E_i-E_f)$$

This rate is defined as 
$$\gamma_{i\to f}=\frac{d}{dt} |\left<f|U(t)|i\right>|^2.$$

**My question:** How should one interpret this differential "rate" physically?

**My thoughts so far:** Apparently it is the derivative of the *transition probability* with respect to time, so it is not a probability itself. In literature it is often called *decay rate*, but for an exponentially decaying probability $p(t)\sim e^{-\lambda t}$ the decay rate $-\lambda$ would not be computed as $dp/dt$, but $(dp/dt)/p$.

Comment: Spontaneous emission.

Comment: @ChrisGerig I dont get your comment, can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: google "fermi golden rule and spontaneous emission", this is standard stuff in the literature

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89402/2451 and links therein.