# Limit of the $\sin^2$ function in the derivation of Fermi's golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

In the derivation of Fermi's golden rule one typically arrives at an expression of the form
$$
\frac{\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2}
$$
which is then converted to 
$$
\pi t\delta(\omega).
$$
I cannot follow this step. I know the following identity 
$$
\delta (\omega) = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin^2(\omega t)}{\pi |t|\omega^2}
$$
from which i would assume that one extends the first expression by $\frac{t}{t}$ and then does the limit. But how can you pull the $t$ out of the limit ? Is this rigorous or is this an approximation ?

I think it should be like this
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{t}{t}\frac{\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2} \not = \pi t\delta(\omega)
$$
and the equation should be 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{t}{t}\frac{\sin^2(\omega t)}{\omega^2} = \pi \delta(\omega) \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}t.
$$
Am i wrong in the above equations ? Otherwise i don't see how Fermi's goldene rule could ever work since we assume at one time that $t$ is so large that we can approximate a function in the limit that $t$ goes to infinity while on the other hand $t$ has to be small such that pertubation theory of first order is accurate. These conditions seem to contradict each other but in every book i find this step. I haven't found any satisfactory answer so far regarding this step. I know the general conditins for pertubation theory but i find the form with the dirac delta function nonsensical. I assume that i go wrong at some point since no one ever brings this point up, please point out my error if i did something wrong.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens the The book by Cohen-Tannoudji, Quantum Mechanics, vol 2 contains this step. He gives a definition of the dirac delta function as a limit in the apendix and then arrives at the expression which stumps me. The expression should still contain the limit as i wrote it in my opinion.

Comment: My problem is mostly of mathematical nature, what happens when you have something like $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty } (f(t)g(x,t) )$, where $g(x,t)$ turns into $\delta (x)$ in this limit. I expect it to be $\delta(x) \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} f(t)$ and not be $f(t) \delta (x)$. The validity of Fermi's golden rule is not my main concern.

Comment: Hi @Hans Wurst: Which page/section/equation in [Cohen-Tannoudji](https://www.google.com/search?as_q="quantum+mechanics"+2&as_epq=cohen+tannoudji)? [Link](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Physics/Quantum%20Mechanics/Cohen-Tannoudji%20C.,%20Diu%20B.,%20Laloe%20F.%20Quantum%20mechanics/).

Comment: @Qmechanic I checked your link and my problem is also contained in the english version. In cohen-tannoudjii_v2.djvu, page 1300 equation C-32. I do not understand how he can pull out a factor of $t$ from the expression $\lim_{t\infty }F(t, \frac{E-E_i}{\hbar})$. In the limit this factor should be evaluated at the limit. I am not sure if he is right or wrong, i would have expected the use of the approximate symbols and not an equality sign. This is why i ask, is it really an equality or just an approximation what is given in equation C-32.

Comment: Duplicate :  [Transition probability derivation: How to prove $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\sin^2\alpha x}{\alpha x^2} ~=~\pi\delta(x)$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240191/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the comments it became clear that OP is trying to understand the formula
   $$ \lim_{t\to\infty} F\left(t,\frac{E-E_i}{\hbar}\right)~=~\pi t~\delta\left(\frac{E-E_i}{2\hbar}\right)~=~2\pi\hbar t~\delta(E-E_i) , \tag{C-32} $$ 
   taken from Ref. 1, where 
   $$ F(t,\omega)~=~\left[\frac{\sin(\omega t/2)}{\omega/2}\right]^2. \tag{C-7} $$
2. It is clear that eq. (C-32) does not make sense as an ordinary [limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)), since the rhs. should then be independent of $t$. (It makes sense as an [asymptotic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion), though.)
3. However, if the goal is just to derive [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule), there is a short-cut: It turns out that the $F$-function (C-7) is proportional to the probability $P(t)$, which grows with time $t$. The trick is to instead consider the quotient $\frac{P(t)}{t}$. Then it becomes mathematically well-defined to consider the limit $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{P(t)}{t}$, i.e. 
   $$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{F\left(t,\frac{E-E_i}{\hbar}\right)}{t}~=~\pi ~\delta\left(\frac{E-E_i}{2\hbar}\right)~=~2\pi\hbar ~\delta(E-E_i) , \tag{C-32'} $$ 
   cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240191/2451) Phys.SE post. This in turn implies that for large enough times $t$ the probability $P(t)$ grows proportionally with $t$, and that the transition rate 
   $$ \frac{dP(t)}{dt}~=~\frac{P(t)}{t} \tag{*}$$
   is given by the proportionality factor.
4. For more details of the proof of Fermi's golden rule, see my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/91794/2451).

References:

1. C. Cohen-Tannoudji, B. Diu & F. Laloe, *QM,* Vol. 2, 1978; Chapter XIII, p. 1283-1302.

Comment: What you wrote in point 2 is what i wanted to clarify. Equation  C-32 is not sensible if you 
are approaching it purely from a mathematical point of view.