# Fermi's golden rule and infinite probablity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, perturbation-theory, approximations, fermis-golden-rule

I am slightly confused about the application of [Fermi's golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule). Which during standard derivations indicates a probability of transitioning from the state $|i \rangle$ to the state $|f\rangle$ of:
$$P=\frac{2\pi t}{\hbar^2} | \langle f | \hat V | i \rangle|^2 \delta(E_f-E_i-\hbar \omega)$$
This holds for large values of $t$ but for arbitrarily large values of $t$:
$$P>1$$
Which (to me anyway) makes no physical sense since there can't be a probability greater then 1 of been in the final state. If my interpretation is right then how is this problem resolved/allowable? and if it is wrong what part of what I have said is wrong?

Comment: The FGR is obtained using TDPT. If you follow the steps carefully, you'll see that the neglected terms are of order $\hat V^2$ **and** $t^2$, so that the approximation is only valid for small values of $t$. A way better approximation is obtained by neglecting $\hat V^2$ but keeping $t$ arbitrary. The result is an something like $P\sim\exp[w_{if}t]-1$, where $w_{if}\propto |\langle f|V|i\rangle|^2$. If you expand to first order in $t$, you get the FGR back. This is thoroughly discussed in any book on TDPT, and in most books on QM.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform But you would only get the form of the probability that I have given in the assumption that $t$ is very large. This is because there is a use of the approximation equivalent to $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{\sin^2(xt)}{x^2}\right)=\pi t \delta(x)$$

Comment: That's somewhat oversimplified.There are several assuptions on the magnitude of $t$. It should be smaller that some constants and larger than some others. I don't remember the details right now, but the assumptions are along the lines of $\tau\ll t\ll T$ for some constants $\tau,T$.The part $t\gg \tau$ is needed to get the delta, but the restriction $t\ll T$ means you cannot take $t\to\infty$. These assumptions arent truly fundamental but simplify the analysis. If you don't restrict the magnitude of $t$ you get the exponential I was talking about. Again, this is addressed in most books on TDPT

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If you put your comments as an answer I will accept it. Further just of note, I think that this answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91794 of Qmechanic's does answer my question (although possibly not the question it was actually posted in).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been discussed in the comment section, and OP has already found the answer in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89402/interpretation-of-transition-rate-in-fermis-golden-rule/91794#91794) wonderful post by QMechanic. In that post, we can clearly see that the magnitude of $t$ is not arbitrary: it has to be bounded both below and above,
$$
\frac{2\pi}{\Delta \omega} \lesssim t \ll \frac{\hbar}{\sup_{f\in F}|V_{fi}|}
$$
where the symbols are defined in QMechanic's post. This is the reason we cannot take $t\to \infty$.

It is useless to reproduce QMechanic's post here, or to try to improve it. Instead, I'll try to address my statement that, if we keep the magnitude of $t$ arbitrary, then the transition probability is an exponential.

In the usual proof of the FGR we find, at some point, the integrodifferential equation
$$
c_i(t)=1-i\sum_n\int_0^tc_n(\tau)V_{ni}(\tau)\; \mathrm e^{-i\omega_{ni}\tau}
$$
and take $c_n(\tau)\approx c_n(0)$ to get the first order correction (from which the FGR follows). This is the step that constrains the magnitude of $t$. If we take $c_n(\tau)\approx c_n(t)$ instead, we find (after some lengthy manipulations)
$$
c_i(t)=\mathrm e^{-\Gamma t/2}\times \text{a phase}
$$
where $\Gamma\propto V_{fi}$ is the decay width of the state. This formula is valid for arbitrarily large $t$. Expanding to first order ($\Gamma t\ll 1$), we get the  usual formulas back. A detailed derivation (and discussion) can be found in the book by Cohen-Tannoudji *Quantum Mechanics*, vol 2., page 1351, "Another approximate method for solving the Schrödinger equation".