# Delta function in Fermi's Golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

I am currently trying to understand the Fermi's golden rule.

We consider a system with Hamiltonian:
$$\hat H = \hat H_0 + \hat Ue^{i \omega t},$$
where the expectation value of $\hat U$ i much smaller than that of $\hat H_0$.

At $t=0$ the systems is in the ground state $\lvert 0 \rangle$ of $\hat H_0$ (we assume that $\hat H_0$ has discrete spectrum). Using first-order, time dependent perturbation theory, we obtain probability of the system being in the state $\lvert n \rangle$ after time $t$:
$$\lvert c_n(t) \rvert^2 = \frac{1}{\hbar^2} \lvert \langle n \rvert \hat U \lvert 0 \rangle \rvert^2 \frac{\sin^2 \left(\frac{(\omega_n - \omega_0 - \omega) t}{2} \right)}{(\frac{\omega_n - \omega_0 - \omega}{2})^2}.$$
As far as I understand, this is the probability (not probability density) that we find the system in a state $\lvert n \rangle$ after time $t$ (if we for example turn off the time dependent potential and measure energy of the system). Now, according to my notes, if we take the limit as $t \to \infty$, this probability tends to:
$$\lvert c_n(t) \rvert^2 = \frac{2\pi t}{\hbar^2} \lvert \langle n \rvert \hat U \lvert 0 \rangle \rvert^2 \delta(\omega_n - \omega_0 - \omega).$$
This expression is infinite (undefined?) when $\omega_n - \omega_0 - \omega = 0$. However, even after a very long time the transition probability should be finite (and while we're at it, than one).

I would normally expect to see dirac delta when dealing with probability densities , however as I mentioned before we are considering transitions between discrete states, so Kronecker delta is what I would expect to see here.

My question is, what am I missing here?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241434/84967 and links therein.

Comment: I disagree that this question is a duplicate (at least, a duplicate of the quoted question).  This question is focused on the Dirac delta term, not the fact that the probability is linearly proportional to $t$.