Fermi's Golden Rule: Interpreting the Dirac Delta in Transition Probabilities
I am trying to understand an aspect of Fermi's golden rule in the case of a constant perturbation, $V$. The formula for the transition probability from an initial state $i$ to a final state $f$ is given by:
$$P_{i \rightarrow f} = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} \tau |V_{i,f}|^2 \delta(E_f - E_i)$$
I understand that the Dirac delta $\delta(E_f - E_i)$ ensures energy conservation by imposing that the transition occurs only when $E_f=E_i$. However, I have a doubt: how can this expression make sense since the Dirac delta goes to infinity when $E_f=E_i$? Shouldn't the transition probability always be less than 1?
I know that the Dirac delta is often used to describe probability densities, but in this case, we are talking about the probability of transitioning from a specific state $i$ to a specific state $f$. Am I missing something about the correct interpretation of the Dirac delta in this context? Could someone clarify how this formula is properly interpreted and how a finite, meaningful transition probability is obtained?

Yeah, I would call that an incomplete derivation of Fermi's golden rule, which requires dividing by $\tau$ and turning this into a rate rather than a probability, and then integrating over the final energies against some sort of density of states. Clearly the interpretation of that quantity as a probability can only be sustained if it's interpreted as a probability density (probability per unit energy range), and that we need to integrate over energy to actually compute a finite probability.

"However, I have a doubt: how can this expression make sense since the Dirac delta goes to infinity when Ef=Ei?" Your expression has to be integrated against the density of states in order to get a probability.

(Dirac delta "function" always has to be integrated against something to make sense as a  function)

@hft yes, I agree! but as I mention in the question, this would mean that we are dealing with a probability density. However, this formula is given as a probability for a two level system

Does this answer your question? Fermi's golden rule and Probabilities in QM

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241434/2451 and links therein.

This paper avioids the delta function, https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/37/6/065406?fromSearchPage=true
