# Feynman, Hibbs Perturbations and Energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

I am currently self-studying from Feynman & Hibbs’ Quantum Mecahnics and Path Integrals, but having an issue understanding a step in their development of first-order perturbations. They define
$$V_{mn}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi_m^*(x)V(x,t)\phi_n(x)\,dx,$$
where $\phi_m(x)$ is an unperturbed eigenfunction with energy $E_m$, and $V(x,t)$ is a perturbing potential. This gives (eventually) the probability of transition from state $n$ to $m$ within time $T$ as
$$P(n\rightarrow m)=\frac{|V_{mn}|^2}{(E_m-E_n)^2}\left[4\sin^2\frac{(E_m-E_n)T}{2\hbar}\right]$$
This all makes sense to me. But on p150, they specialise to the case where values of the final energy, $E_m$, lie in a continuum, defining $\rho(E)\,dE$ as the number of states with energy lying between $E$ and $E+dE$. We now have, as the probability of any transition:
$$\int|V_{mn}|^2\frac{4\sin^2[(E_m-E_n)T/2\hbar]}{(E_m-E_n)^2}\rho(E_m)\,dE_m$$
At this point, they spend some time demonstrating that the final states that contribute most to this integral will be those with energy $E_m$ that is *in the neighbourhood of*, *nearly*, or *approximately* the same as $E_n$ (all three descriptions are used). They then use the approximation that $|V_{mn}|$ and $\rho(E_m)$ vary slowly enough in this neighbourhood that we can treat them as constant, taking them outside the integral. Using $\int_{-\infty}^\infty[(sin^2 x)/x^2]\,dx = \pi$, they write (p151) “we obtain the result that the probability for a transition to some state in the continuum is
$$P(n\rightarrow m)=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|V_{mn}|^2\rho(E_n)T,$$
and that the energy in the final state is *the same as* the energy in the initial state.” (emphasis mine).

I have no issue following the mathematics up to this final result, but I cannot see why they have moved from describing the final energy as lying in the continuum, *approximately* equal to the initial energy, to claiming the *result* that it is *the same*. A few paragraphs later, they explicitly replace $\rho(E_n)$ with $\delta(E_m-E_n)$, but again, I can’t see why.

They have not indicated that this result arises from $T\rightarrow\infty$; could that be what I am missing?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89402/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the contribution is from state close to $E_n$, they can assume that the level density doesn't vary much in that within that range in energy. Replace $\rho(E_m)$ with its value at $E_n$. The delta comes from

$\frac{\sin^2(xT)}{Tx^2} \rightarrow \pi \delta(x), T \rightarrow \infty.
$