# Relativistic Fermi Golden Rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, fermis-golden-rule

On online slide notes, it is mentioned that:

Fermi Golden Rule:
$$P_{if}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|M_{if}|^2\rho_f$$ where $\rho_f$ is density of final sates --number of quantum states per unit volume - states in a cubical box wih side $l$ wih periodic boundary conditions - $\overrightarrow{p}=2\pi \overrightarrow{n}/l$

$$dp(p)=\frac{nbofstates}{l^3}=\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi )^3}$$

Then he wrote: $$\frac{d^3p}{2E(2\pi )^3}=\theta(p^0)\delta(p^2) \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^3}$$

and said **conventional** to make this relativistic.

I did not understand how can this be conventional? That is I did not understand also how did this derive from the Non-Relativistic equation above.

Comment: More on relativistic FGR: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12034/2451

Comment: Yes, I saw that one but it is the $\theta(p^0)$ that worries me and the *conventional* part. @Qmechanic

Comment: It's "conventional" because there would be others ways to write down a Lorentz invariant measure, but this is the one used. For *why* this is a Lorentz invariant measure, see [joshphysics' answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/53567/50583) to another question.

Comment: Which online slide notes?