# Relation between differential cross section and Fermi's Golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section, fermis-golden-rule

It is stated and it seems also reasonable that from [Fermi's Golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule) one should be able to obtain the differential cross-section (in first Born approximation). Does anyone know how to derive their relationship or give some reference?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12034/2451

Comment: I apologise, my tablet won't copy the link, but if you Google **Scattering and Decays from Fermi's Golden Rule including all the ¯h's and c's", it's a pdf that seems to incorporate the Golden rule into the Born approximation, to what degree though  I am not sure, scroll down about 3/4 of the pdf.

Comment: @count_to_10 [Here's the link](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~schwitte/PHY362L/QMnote.pdf)